# using ssh-agent without login

Tags: python, linux, ssh, paramiko, ssh-agent

We would like to use ssh-agent to automatically connect to many machines through ssh, using a dedicated user on a ubuntu machine (12.04); the problem is that since we have generated this user through a script

```
useradd -m -s /bin/bash USER
```

and we don't login to that user, the ssh-agent is not running and any attempt to use ssh without providing a password (we use python and paramiko) fails saying

```
no autentication methods available
```

we have done some research, and found out that many people would start ssh-agent with this command-line

```
eval "ssh-agent"
```

but this won't work for us (especially when the above command is executed through python).

The only way to make it work is to login to that user (through ssh for instance) and type the above comand, which make our automated approach not so automated: is there a way to make ssh-agent start at startup without the need to login to the dedicated user?

Comment: What happens when connecting with disabling the agent ? `ssh.connect(...., allow_agent=False`) ?

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at [Salt](http://saltstack.org/), it probably has already the functionality you are going to implement :)

Comment: If this question is about "How can I start ssh-agent as service" (what I think) it should be at http://serverfault.com/.

Comment: @Tisho disabling the agent worked just fine, i didn't knew that it was possible to automatically use ssh without it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question will be better answered in the [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) website.

But, here is an idea.

Create an init script on all the pcs, such that when the pc starts, it logs in as the user and starts ssh-agent and logs out. Set the init script run level to start whenever the pc starts in normal/multi-user mode.

Comment: I think your idea is too overthought :) Probably he wants just that `ssh-agent` is launched as service.

Comment: That's also a good idea, but as @Tisho pointed out, our particular setup (python + paramiko) can be used without ssh-agent: thanks for your answer though